# Swift : Only transfers certain variable when using prepareforsegue function

Tags: swift, xcode, segue, transfer

I am using the prepareforsegue function to transfer data between view controllers. I am attempting to transfer the data held by 5 variables yet only 4 transfer. I am wondering if it is a formatting issue considering the 4 that transfer correctly have different variable types to the other. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

### Sender View Controller

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

    class CratesViewController : UIViewController {

    var unlockedAK47 = "false"
    var unlockedDesertEagle = "false"
    var unlockedGlock17 = "false"
    var unlockedGlock18 = "false"

    var coinsAmount = 0
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

    @IBOutlet weak var coins: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cratesImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var unlockView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var backButtonOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var gunImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        coins.text = String(coinsAmount)
        gunImageView.isHidden = true

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "cratesToMainSegue" {

            let destViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController

            destViewController.unlockedAK47 = unlockedAK47
            destViewController.unlockedDesertEagle = unlockedDesertEagle
            destViewController.unlockedGlock17 = unlockedGlock17
            destViewController.unlockedGlock18 = unlockedGlock18
            destViewController.coinsAmount = coinsAmount

        }

    }

}
```

### Destination View Controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var unlockedAK47 = "false"
    var unlockedDesertEagle = "false"
    var unlockedGlock17 = "true"
    var unlockedGlock18 = "false"

    struct defaultsKeys {
        static let keyOne = ""
    }

    var coinsAmount = 100

    @IBOutlet weak var coinsAmountLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Getting

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let stringOne = defaults.string(forKey: defaultsKeys.keyOne) {
            coinsAmount = Int(stringOne)!
        }

        coinsAmountLabel.text = String(coinsAmount)

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        // Note that the segue identifiers have been set in the interface builder

        if segue.identifier == "cratesSegue" {

            let destViewController = segue.destination as! CratesViewController

            destViewController.coinsAmount = coinsAmount

            destViewController.unlockedAK47 = unlockedAK47
            destViewController.unlockedDesertEagle = unlockedDesertEagle
            destViewController.unlockedGlock17 = unlockedGlock17
            destViewController.unlockedGlock18 = unlockedGlock18

        } else if segue.identifier == "collectionSegue" {

            let destViewController = segue.destination as! CollectionViewController

            destViewController.coinsAmount = coinsAmount

            destViewController.unlockedAK47 = unlockedAK47
            destViewController.unlockedDesertEagle = unlockedDesertEagle
            destViewController.unlockedGlock17 = unlockedGlock17
            destViewController.unlockedGlock18 = unlockedGlock18

        }

    }

    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {

        coinsAmount = coinsAmount + 10
        coinsAmountLabel.text = String(coinsAmount)

        // Saving

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(String(coinsAmount), forKey: defaultsKeys.keyOne)

    }

}
```

Please let me know if any more information is needed. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not because `coinsAmount` is a different type. This is because `coinsAmount`'s value is overwritten in `viewDidLoad`:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
if let stringOne = defaults.string(forKey: defaultsKeys.keyOne) {
    coinsAmount = Int(stringOne)! <<<< HERE!
}
```

I think what you want to do is to get the coins amount only if it is not passed to `ViewController`.

You should declare `coinsAmount` as an optional:

```
var coinsAmount: Int!
```

And check whether it is nil before overwriting it, so that you don't accidentally overwrite the passed value.

```
if coinsAmount == nil {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if let stringOne = defaults.string(forKey: defaultsKeys.keyOne) {
        coinsAmount = Int(stringOne)!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much; I really appreciate it :) Making a game for my cousin and I can't wait to finish it